# Chromedp golang send ctrl+a

Tags: golang, chromedp

Автоматизирую работу в браузере и столкнулся с необходимостью отправлять комбинации клавиш. Например shift+end
Пробовал

```
if err := chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.SendKeys(`#element`, kb.shift+kb.End)); err != nil {
   panic(err)
}
```

Но в таком случае отправляет по очереди, а не одновременно. Необходимо отправлять события нажатия клавиш keyDown и KeyUp, но просмотрев весь интернет и почитав множество примеров я не смог разобраться, как это работает и воспроизвести.

Пробовал отправлять события нажатия подобным образом:

```
if err := chromedp.Run(ctx, input.DispatchKeyEvent(input.KeyDown).WithKey(kb.Shift)); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

Но так же не происходит нужного мне результата.

Comment: `DispatchKeyEvent(input.KeyDown).WithKey(kb.Shift)` отправляет нажатие шифта. Попробуйте `DispatchKeyEvent(input.KeyDown).WithKey("A").WithModifiers(input.ModifierCtrl)`

Comment: Теоретически это должно быть верно, но моя задача встроить это в контекст chromedp.Run
В таком случае должно выглядить наподобии:

chromedp.DispatchKeyEvent(input.KeyDown).WithKey(kb.Shift) но нет такого метода в chromedp. Возможно должно помочь что-то вроде chromedp.Action или chromedp.ActionFunc но опять таки не смог точно понять, как именно это реализовать.